# Sobre passagem por referência e por valor

Tags: visualg

Não consigo entender quando usar um ou outro. neste código, usei as duas formas e não vi alteração no final. Qual a diferença e quando devo usar um ou outro

Crie um procedimento que receba dois valores por referência e ordene-os
em ordem crescente. Crie um algoritmo principal para chamar o
procedimento e exibir os valores após a ordenação.

```
Algoritmo "procedimento"

Var
 x, y: inteiro

   Procedimento crescente(var A,B: inteiro)
   var
   cres: inteiro
   inicio

   Se (a < b) entao
         para cres de a ate b faca
            Escreva(cres)
            cres <- cres + 1
         fimpara
      Senao
        para cres de b ate a faca
             Escreva(cres)
             cres <- cres + 1
        fimpara
      Fimse

   FimProcedimento

Inicio

  x <- 10
  y <- 20


  crescente(x, y)

Fimalgoritmo
```

Answer (score 0):

Fiz um pequenos ajustes no seu programa. Não fique triste comigo! : )

Procurei explicar da melhor forma possível!

Algoritmo "procedimento"

```
Inicio

    Var x, y: inteiro

    x <- 10 
    y <- 20

    crescente(x, y) 

    escreva(x)
    escreva(y)

Fim 

/* 
  Comentario:
    Neste procedimento o primeiro parâmetro A é passagem por referência, porque precede de var, 
                           então o valor de A será alterado mudando o valor de x.
                       o segundo parâmetro B é passagem por valor, 
                           então o valor de B será alterado SOMENTE dentro do procedimento e não vai alterar o valor de y.
*/ 
Procedimento crescente(var A, B: inteiro) 

  inicio
        Se (A < B) entao 
            para A ate B faca 
                Escreva(A) 
                A <- A + 1 
            fim-para
        Senao
             para B ate A faca 
                Escreva(B) 
                B <- B + 1 
             fim-para
        fim-se
   fim

Fim-Procedimento
```

Fim-algoritmo

Vamos executar o seu programa:

X = 10  (Valor inicial)
Y = 20  (Valor inicial)

fez a chamada do procedimento: crescente(10,20)

executando dentro do procedimento crescente:

A = 10
B = 20

Como 10 é menor do que 20 vai entrar na primeira condição (Se (A < B)).
Então vai executar o laço de repetição (para) vai executar de 10 a 20 e acaba a estrutura de repetição.

A = 10
exibe 10 
A = 11 
exibe 11
...
A=20

sai do procedimento crescente.

acrescentei dois comandos escreva para x e y depois do procedimento crescente.

exibe 20 (valor final de x)
exibe 20 (valor final de y)

Boa prática de programação é fazer uma boa indentação do seu código para tornar claro o entendimento do código e ajuda muito na manutenção (possíveis mudanças que precisam ser feitas).

[visualg]

Comment: Obrigado, é um pouco confuso pra mim. Aliás bastante. Vou rodar esse código, digamos que se eu tirar o var, pra ver o que acontece

Comment: Por nada! Se tirar o VAR o parâmetro torna-se por valor.  O VAR que define parâmetro por referência. No início é assim mesmo, tem que persistir, pois com a prática que aprende.